# My Angular application is redirecting to login screen after refresh is hit

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication

I'm attaching the code below, please provide me a solution I have tried this.router.navigateByUrl('/home') and also using URLTree before, they did not work.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "./helpers/auth.guard";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "home", component: AppComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | UrlTree {
    let url: string = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }
  checkLogin(url: string): true | UrlTree {
    console.log("Url: " + url)
    let val: string = localStorage.getItem('isUserLoggedIn');
    if (val != null && val == "true") {
      if (url == "/login")
        this.router.parseUrl('/home');
      else
        return true;
    } else {
      return this.router.parseUrl('/login');
    }
  }
}
```

authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { tap, delay } from "rxjs/operators";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AppConstants } from "../AppConstants";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  isUserLoggedIn: boolean = false;
  public validLog$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  private apiUrl = AppConstants.baseURL + "/api/login";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const credentials = { username, password };
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, credentials);
  }
  logout(): void {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
    this.setProfileObs(false);
    localStorage.removeItem("isUserLoggedIn");
  }
  getProfileObs(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.validLog$.asObservable();
  }
  setProfileObs(val: boolean) {
    this.validLog$.next(val);
  }
}
```

I have tried this. router. navigate By Url ('/home') and also using URL Tree before

But the application is still logging out after refresh button , I want it to stay on /home even if the refresh is hit

Comment: Java and Javascript are not the same

Comment: And where you write the "isUserLoggedIn" value? Is it in the locale storage? (Browser - Dev Console - application)

Comment: @Flo It's Defined in authentication.service.ts as an boolean value , Please provide solution if you can